# Defining a function to calculate IQR in Numpy

Tags: python

I'm trying to define a function to calculate IQR in numpy. The code is really simple but I keep getting an error message I can't figure out

```
def calculate_icq(variable):
icq = 0
icq += (np.percentile(df.variable, 75) - np.percentile(df.variable, 25))

return icq
```

When i run the function using one of the column variables (say calculate_icq('Price')) it says  'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'variable'

Shouldn't the term 'Price' map onto variable and replace it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't call columns like that. You need to use `df[variable]`.

```
def calculate_icq(variable):
    icq = 0
    icq += (np.percentile(df[variable], 75) - np.percentile(df[variable], 25))

    return icq
```